# Scrolling ListView populates dummy values

Tags: android, listview, scroll

My listview contains one image,and some textview; there are two textiview which contains the price and special price,if special price is 0 than set only price textview and special price let it null,but special price is > 0 than set price value as well special price,fisrt time everything is going good but when i am scrolling the listview then blank textview set with dumyy value`enter code here`

Here is my getView method code.

```
@Override
public     View     getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
//public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    /*View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }
    */
    int pos=position;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txt_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id); // title
        viewHolder.txt_product_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        viewHolder.artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist
                                                                    // name
        viewHolder.txt_mspecialprice_withouttax = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
        viewHolder.stock = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stck);
        viewHolder.txt_mprice_withouttax = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtmpricewithouttax);

        viewHolder.thumb_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb
                                                                                // image


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    String mspecialprice_str=song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PRODUCT_MSPECIAL_WITHOUT_TAX);
    //String substr_mspecialprice_str=mspecialprice_str.substring(1,mspecialprice_str.indexOf("."));
    //String substr_mspecialprice_str_replaced=substr_mspecialprice_str.replace(",", "");

    String msaleprice_str=song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PRODUCT_MPRICE_WITHOUT_TAX);
    //String substr_msaleprice_str=msaleprice_str.substring(0,msaleprice_str.indexOf("."));
    //String substr_msaleprice_str_replaced=substr_msaleprice_str.replace(",", "");

    viewHolder.txt_id.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PRODUCT_ID));
    viewHolder.txt_product_name.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PRODUCT_NAME));
    viewHolder.artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION));
    viewHolder.stock.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_STOCK));
    if(mspecialprice_str.equals("0"))
    {
        //txt_mspecialprice_withouttax.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PRODUCT_MSPECIAL_WITHOUT_TAX));
        viewHolder.txt_mprice_withouttax.setText("$"+(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PRODUCT_MPRICE_WITHOUT_TAX)));

        viewHolder.txt_mprice_withouttax.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#64aef9"));

    }
    //if(!(mspecialprice_str.equals("0")))
    //{
else
{
    viewHolder.txt_mspecialprice_withouttax.setText("$"+(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PRODUCT_MSPECIAL_WITHOUT_TAX)));
    viewHolder.txt_mprice_withouttax.setText("$"+(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PRODUCT_MPRICE_WITHOUT_TAX)));
    viewHolder.txt_mprice_withouttax.setPaintFlags(viewHolder.txt_mprice_withouttax.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    viewHolder.txt_mprice_withouttax.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F01616"));
}

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(
            song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PRODUCT_IMAGEURL), viewHolder.thumb_image);

    return convertView;
}
}

class ViewHolder {
TextView txt_id ; // title
TextView txt_product_name; // title
TextView artist ; // artist
                                                            // name
TextView txt_mspecialprice_withouttax; // duration
TextView stock ;
TextView txt_mprice_withouttax;

ImageView thumb_image ; // thumb


}
```

Comment: if you can tell us why you want to do this ? I believe you are face some other issue and you need to rephrase the question you are asking here.

Comment: actually what happen here let me tell you in detail,my listview contains one image,and some textview,there are two textiview which contains the price and special price,if special price is 0 than set only price textview and special price let it null,but special price is > 0 than set price value as well special price,fisrt time everything is going good but when i am scrolling the listview then blank textview set with dumyy value.

Comment: pls edit your question with what u just mentioned in ur comment

Answer (score 1):

ListView, GridView reuse views used as list items/grid elements.  getView() is called everytime android tries to draw next element while scrolling your view.  There is no need to prevent that!

**Edit - [Atrix1987](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1752193/atrix1987)**

From the developer [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

> > An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the underlying data for that view. The Adapter provides access to the data items. The Adapter is also responsible for making a View for each item in the data set.

Suppose you have 10 elements which you want to show using your GridView/ListView and the maximum visible items is 5 then the same 5 views can be reused to display the rest of the 5 elements when you scroll. This is the intended behavior and is the right way to do things [keeps number of views to a minimum].

You don't have control on `getView` method, the framework does that for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i want to execute getview method only one time after data loaded into listview/gridview then i dont want to execute getview method again

Comment: every time my listview item position is changed,so i dont want to change listview item position also

Comment: getView() isn't called after that is loaded -- it's called when listview wants to draw something.
imagine you have 100 elements in your data adapter but listview only shows 10 elements at a time -- you will get 10 getView() calls. only 10 as only 10 are needed to show listview.
this is how listview/gridview works.

Comment: ok let the getview call again and again but i dont want to changing my listview row position and as well its value.pls help me here.

Answer (score 0):

The `GridView` widget extends `AdapterView`. It uses the adapter to allow the reuse of Views and improve performance. There is no way to avoid calling `getView()` - it is essential to the whole `AdapterView` idea. If you want a static layout, perhaps you should use something else.

Comment: ok let the getview call again and again but i dont want to changing my listview row position and as well its value.pls help me here.

Comment: OK, you don't really understand the concept of adapters. Read up on the matter and you'll see that changing the position is (again) essential to the idea - each call to getView returns the view for a single object at a specified position. How can it *not* change?

Comment: So did our answers help you? If not, answer your question yourself.